# Open VPN configuration error

Tags: xubuntu

I have installed openvpn and I have downloaded the **.ovpn** file but unable to import the file in **network settings> vpn> import file option**.
Result:

```
Cannot import VPN connection
The filen vpn.ovpn could not be read or does not contain recognized VPN connection information
Error: configuration error: unsupported blob/xml element(line 78)
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Try to provide a *little* more detail.  Where'd you get the config file?  Whare are you trying to import it into?  Have you tried to open the file in anything else to see what it contains?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install **network-manager-openvpn** package.

Also check your file is correct. Try to use a free VPN, if it works find a mistake in your vpn.ovpn file.